# scikit-learn でエラー: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

Tags: python, 機械学習, scikit-learn

sklearnでトレーニングテータとテストデータを分けて決定木アルゴリズムにフィットさせようとしたところエラーが起きました。
解決方法がわからないため、もしよかったら指摘よろしくお願いします。

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import csv
csvfile = open('BioAsseT practice data5.csv')
df = pd.read_csv("BioAsseT practice data5.csv")
X= df.external
y= df.total
X.shape, y.shape
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train_val, X_test, y_train_val, y_test=train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)
X_train, X_val,  y_train, y_val, =train_test_split(X_train_val, y_train_val, test_size=0.5, random_state=1)
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)

dtree.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-97e56a26e4dc> in <module>
----> 1 dtree.fit(X_train,y_train)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    935         """
    936 
--> 937         super().fit(
    938             X,
    939             y,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    163             check_X_params = dict(dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
    164             check_y_params = dict(ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
--> 165             X, y = self._validate_data(
    166                 X, y, validate_separately=(check_X_params, check_y_params)
    167             )

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    576                 # :(
    577                 check_X_params, check_y_params = validate_separately
--> 578                 X = check_array(X, **check_X_params)
    579                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    580             else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    767             # If input is 1D raise error
    768             if array.ndim == 1:
--> 769                 raise ValueError(
    770                     "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:\narray={}.\n"
    771                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[34.2 54.8 47.1 69.7 61.9 51.1 48.3 69.7 55.2 68.5 49.2 61.9 66.  61.8
 51.1 79.7 58.8 67.6 55.2 48.7 67.  56.2 62.5 48.  65.6 40.8 27.6 44.6
 31.6 43.7 40.1 69.7 61.2 50.  70.3 70.  53.3 53.8 42.4 47.1 40.9 74.3
 62.9 61.5 70.9 32.8].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーの内容から推測すると，`X` をデータフレームに変換すればエラーは生じなくなると思われます。

```
# X = df.external
X = pd.DataFrame(df.external)
```

御参考として Iris データを基に類似の状況を作りエラーが発生する場合と（`X` をデータフレームに変換して）エラーが発生しなくなる場合を切り替えられる記述例を示します。12行目と13行目のコメントアウトで切り替えられます。

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris['data'], columns=iris['feature_names'])
df['target'] = iris['target']
# print(f'df:\n{df}')

X = df['petal width (cm)']  # error occurs
# X = pd.DataFrame(df['petal width (cm)'])  # no error occurs
y = df['target']

X_tv, X_test, y_tv, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1,
                                              random_state=11)
X_train, X_val,  y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_tv, y_tv, test_size=0.5,
                                                   random_state=11)
dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
dtree.fit(X_train, y_train)
acc = accuracy_score(y_test, dtree.predict(X_test))
print(f'accuracy: {acc:.4f}')
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。修正してみます。

Answer (score 0):

実際のデータをみない限り診断しにくいですが、１つの特徴量でフィットしようとしているようですので、エラーメッセージの中にある「Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.」という指示に従って`dtree.fit(X_train,y_train)`を実行する前に

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(1, -1)
```

を実行すれば良いのではないかと思われます。

Comment: 指摘ありがとうございます。上記のやり方で修正しようと思います。